# getting the sum of each item on a DBtable and comparing it to another DBtable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table products and I want to get the total number of ordered products based on my product table

this is my product table

```
products
+---------------+-------------------+
| product_id    |    product_name   |
+---------------+-------------------+
|     1         |       ice cream   |
|     2         |        iced tea   |
|     3         |         cake      |
|     4         |   orange juice    |
|     5         |   coconut drink   |
|     5         |   coconut shake   |
+---------------+-------------------+
```

this is my order_items table

```
+---------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------+
|   order_id    |    product_name   |   product_qty  |    product_id |
+---------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------+
|     1         |       ice cream   |        5       |      1        |
|     1         |        iced tea   |        10      |      2        |
|     1         |      cake         |        10      |      3        |
|     1         |    orange juice   |        10      |      4        |
|     2         |       ice cream   |        5       |      1        |
|     2         |        iced tea   |        10      |      2        |
|     2         |      cake         |        10      |      3        |
|     2         |    orange juice   |        10      |      4        |
|     3         |       ice cream   |        5       |      1        |
|     3         |        iced tea   |        10      |      2        |
|     3         |      cake         |        10      |      3        |
|     3         |    orange juice   |        10      |      4        |
+---------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

my expected result is like this

```
ice cream      =  15
iced tea       =  30
cake           =  30 
orange juice   =  30
coconut drink  =  0
coconut shake  =  0
```

I tried using this code as a referrence but I don't know much about inner join

```
SELECT t.timeasd 
from   time t 
left join (
          select time_reserved, 
                 date_reservation 
          from   reservations 
          where  date_reservation = '$res_date'
          ) as q 
      on t.timeasd = q.time_reserved 
where q.date_reservation is null 
      AND t.status='active';
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the question with what I tried to do with the problem, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select product_name, sum(product_qty) sum_product_qty
from order_items 
group by product_id, product_name
```

Side note: your model is not properly normalized. You should not be storing the names of the products in the orders table: this information belongs to the products table. You should store only the id of the product in the order table, and then you would get the results with a join:

```
select p.product_name, coalesce(sum(o.product_qty), 0) sum_product_qty
from products p
left join order_items o on p.product_id = o.product_id
group by p.product_id, p.product_name
```

Comment: the first one works great, but I also want to include the ones that has 0 results/ match on my order_items table, so that the result would return with coconut drink  =  0
coconut shake  =  0

Comment: @reveberces: you can use the second query for this (I just updated it).

Comment: same result. it still dont show me the ones with 0 match

Comment: @reveberces: give it another try please.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query for your problem.

```
SELECT p.product_name
    ,ISNULL(SUM(oi.product_qty), o) AS OrderedQty
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN Order_Item AS oi ON p.product_id = oi.product_id
GROUP BY product_name
```

OR

```
SELECT p.product_name
    ,COALESCE(SUM(oi.product_qty)) AS OrderedQty
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN Order_Item AS oi ON p.product_id = oi.product_id
GROUP BY product_name
```